# Using Regular Expressions in Java - how can you capture two sets of outer parenthesis when they contain nested parenthesis and string literals?

Tags: java, regex

I am having trouble with my Regular Expression to capture the correct sets of parenthesis. In my method I have:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s*union\\s+(\\(.+\\)|\\S+)\\s+and\\s+(\\(.+\\)|\\S+)\\s*;\\s*", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

    if(matcher.matches())
    {
        group1 = matcher.group(1);
        group2 = matcher.group(2);
    }
```

I want to capture either a word or the contents inside the outer parenthesis. In simple cases this works correctly (i.e. if the input is `union a or b;` or `union (union a and b) and c;` or even `union (intersect table1 and table2) and (minus table4 and (union table1 and table2));`
)


But if the input is:

```
union (union a and b) and (union (union a and c) and d);
```

I get:

```
group1 = union a and b) and (union (union a and c
group2 = table1)
```

But I want group1 and group2 to be:

```
group1 = union a and b
group2 = union (union a and c) and d
```

*In similar inputs it seems to be capturing from the last 'and'. Another example:*

```
input = union (union a and b) and (union (union c and d) and (union e and f));
group1 = (union a and b) and (union (union c and d)
group2 = (union e and f))
```

How can capture the correct set of parenthesis?

Comment: this activity seems like it would be more suited to a parser than a regular expression to me

Comment: Time for a link to the imfamous post?

Comment: Java's regex doesn't have enough power to parse arbitrarily deep nested parentheses.

Comment: @nhahtdh It has nothing to do with Java. It is a fundamental limitation of regular expressions.

Comment: @EJP: Perl parses these for breakfast. PCRE and .NET can only pick the outer most parentheses, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't parse with a scanner. You need a parser. Regular expressions cannot handle nested parentheses. They are the wrong technology for this task.

Comment: Thank you. I guess I was hoping I could maybe use a lookahead somehow to look for the semicolon and make what I had work.